# How to handle server sided output with Javascript in R

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I'd like to show 1 question first and when this toggle is activated show the next question. But Javascript doesn't seem to know what my ID is which I make in server.R

App.R:

```
library(shiny.fluent)

if (interactive()) {
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluentPage(
      tags$script(src = "./www/questions.js"),
      reactOutput("modalQuestions")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      modalVisibleQuestions <- reactiveVal(TRUE)
      observeEvent(input$showQuestions, modalVisibleQuestions(TRUE))
      observeEvent(input$hideQuestions, modalVisibleQuestions(FALSE))
      observeEvent(input$krijgAdvies, modalVisibleQuestions(FALSE))
      observeEvent(input$showModal, modalVisible(TRUE))
      output$modalQuestions <- renderReact({
        Modal(
          isOpen = modalVisibleQuestions(),
          Stack(
            tokens = list(padding = "15px", childrenGap = "10px"),
            div(
              style = list(display = "flex"),
              Text("Extra vragen", variant = "large"),
              div(style = list(flexGrow = 1)),
            ),
            div(
              p("Gaat u nog bolus toedienen 3u voor de start van de activiteit?"),
              Toggle.shinyInput("toggle1", value = FALSE),
              textOutput("toggleValue1"),
              div(
                id = "vraag_2_not_within_60_minutes",
                p("Heeft u deze dosis bolus al ingenomen?"),
                Toggle.shinyInput("toggle3", value = FALSE),
                textOutput("toggleValue3")
              ),
              p("Gaat u nog bolus toedienen 1u voor de start van de activiteit?"),
              Toggle.shinyInput("toggle2", value = FALSE),
              textOutput("toggleValue2"),
              PrimaryButton.shinyInput(style = "background-color: #47bcc9", "krijgAdvies", text = "Advies")
            )
          )
        )
      })
    }
  )
}
```

questions.js (INSIDE FOLDER www):

```
var bolus3h_button = document.getElementById("toggle1")
var bolus1h_button = document.getElementById("toggle2")
var bolus_taken_button = document.getElementById("toggle3")

var vraag2 = document.getElementById("vraag_2_not_within_60_minutes")
vraag2.style.visibility = hidden
```

This questions.js file is already sourced in my router file so this isn't the problem. The questions do get shown as well. So the only question that remains is how do I get a server-sided ID in javascript?

Comment: It would be useful if you provide an example of R code that we can replicate.

Comment: @EmmanuelHamel I'm sorry I will edit the question and you'll find my app.R